# How to filter Duplicate result from output SELECT Query

Tags: php, mysql, select, unique, distinct

i have a code where i'm trying to output data from my mysql table using the select query but i cant figure out how to make it that it returns just one of each student irrespective of the number of subjects they are offering by the teacher, because as I have it if they are offering 2 subjects from the teacher, they tend to appear twice (once for each subject even though each one holds data for the two they offer)

here's how my code is written;

```
 while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
 $i++;
 $sr_id[$i]=$row1['id'];
}

 $sql2="select distinct student.i_name as std_name,student.id as std_id, student.index_number 
as std_index,subject_routing.subject_id as s_id
   from student_subject
   inner join student
   on student_subject.index_number=student.index_number
   inner join subject_routing
   on student_subject.sr_id=subject_routing.id
   where (student_subject.year='$year' and student_subject.sr_id='$sr_id[0]') or 
(student_subject.year='$year' and student_subject.sr_id='$sr_id[1]')";
          
$result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
$count=0;
if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0){
    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    $count++;
    $subject_id=$row2['s_id'];
    $std_index=$row2["std_index"];
?>
<tr>
                    <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
                    <td id="td1_<?php echo $row2['std_id']; ?>">
                        <a href="#modalviewform" 
onClick="studentProfile('<?php echo $row2["std_index"]; ?>')" class=""  
data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $row2['std_name']; ?></a>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
<?php } } ?>
```

Note; i tried using Distinct on the student index and it stopped ouputting any data at all.

for instant i have Student Table as

id   index   name

1. 1001   Jason
2. 1002   Anita
3. 1003   Jack
4. 1004   Sasha

then i have the Student_subject table as

id   index   sr_id
1    1001     13
2    1001     14
3    1002     13
4    1004     13
5    1004     14

then the final table Subject_routing as

id      teacher_index

12         10
13         11
14         11
15         12
16         10

so what i'm trying to do is display all students offering atleast one subject by the teacher once on a page

Comment: Can you also provide the schema for these tables? Or better, the minimal schema that represents your data model and issue, with extra fields excluded. And finally, can you provide sample data along with what you want/expect for an outcome?

Comment: What builds `$result1`? I'd look at adjusting that to include all the data you require. For the issue described a `group by` seems like it'd solve the issue.